# Prior for $\lambda$ is LASSO prior?

Tags: bayesian, lasso, prior, uninformative-prior

I have a regression model with regression coefficients $\beta_j$, $j=1,...,n$, and I would like to use a LASSO prior for $\beta_j$, this is:

$$\beta_j \sim Laplace(0,1/\lambda),$$

where the Laplace density function is $\pi(\beta_j\vert b) = \dfrac{1}{2b}\exp\left(-\dfrac{\vert \beta_j \vert}{b}\right)$.  What priors are typically used in the literature for $\lambda$? I was thinking of using a "non informative" Gamma or Inverse Gamma, but I wanted to check if there are some better choices?

Comment: see http://faculty.chicagobooth.edu/workshops/econometrics/past/pdf/asp047v1.pdf or http://www.stat.ufl.edu/archived/casella/Papers/Lasso.pdf

Comment: further list of references: [Park and Casella (2008)](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1198/016214508000000337), [Rajaratnam and Sparks (2015)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.03697)